# How do I rescue a method when there is nil user?

Tags: ruby, null, rescue

From time to time I have user.id == nil. And when this happens my lookup fails. What is the most practical way to rescue this code? and what do you typically return when this happens?

```
def lookup  
  @data[user.id]["email"]
end
```

Say a mail method is using the returned value

```
email(lookup).deliver
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
begin
  @data[user.id]["email"]
rescue Exception
  nil
end
```

or you might be able to do

```
@date[user.try(:id)]["email"]
```

which will just return nil if user is nil and you call id on it.

The real problem here is that you've got a code smell.  Whatever class owns the `lookup` method knows too much about the implementation details of @data.  I can't recommend a fix without more code, but I'd suggest writing a method/class that only knows how to pull the email out of data.  Something like:

```
@data.get_email_for_user
```

That way this class wouldn't have to worry about whether or not user is nil.  It only has to worry about returning the email.

Answer (score 0):

`user.id.nil? ? <default return val here> : @data[user.id]["email"]`

Or, if you don't want to return anything:

`@data[user.id]["email"] if user.id`